# Java code using Set showing weird output?

Tags: java, algorithm

The output of the following code should be 1 according to my logic. But its showing 100 instead. Can anyone explain me where is the problem?

```
  /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Set<Short> s=new HashSet<Short>();
        for(Short i=0;i<100;i++){
            s.add(i);
            s.remove(i-1);
        }
        System.out.println(s.size());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of

```
i-1
```

is of type `int`.

This is described in the Java Language Specification, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2).

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

This `int` value then gets [boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) to `Integer` in order to be used as an argument to `Set#remove(Object)`.

The `remove(Object)` method then uses this `Integer` object to compare to the elements in the `Set`, using `Object#equals(Object)`. But no `Short` is `equals` to an `Integer` and no `Integer` is `equal` to a `Short`. And therefore nothing gets removed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lays in out- and autoboxing:

The statement i-1 is of type `int` not of type `Short`.
The method `remove()` accepts a parameter of type `Object` (not necessarily the Generic type of the collection). Java will auto-box the numeric value as an Integer. The Integer cannot be found in the set and will thus not be removed.